# Why is my HTML/CSS collapsible not working?

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a collapsible segment on a webpage and so far have just tried the examples from W3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp. When I click the 'current' button the div does not become expanded.

I understand that the button tag needs to be directly next to the section to be collapsed, which I have. By playing around with the Inspect feature on my browser, it looks like the content.style.display setting is not being set properly on a click, as manually toggling it produces the desired effect. I looked at similar questions which suggested using this.parentNode.nextElementSibling instead of this.nextElementSibling, but this just produced the same behaviour. Does the location of the  tag matter?  Below is a snippet of the code - in essence just the code from the W3 website.

```js
const coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
   coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        let content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
                 content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
                 content.style.display = "block";
        }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
}
.content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.active, .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">current</button>
<div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: just remove the property in content class `max-height: 0;` other way, regardless of the display value it will always be 0 the height

Comment: @RubenSaucedo apologies, that was a bad copy/paste. Updated the code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your JavaScript code.

It should be looking like this:

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
              
for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Your code should be looking like this (full version):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .collapsible {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      .content {
        padding: 0 18px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      }
      .active,
      .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">current</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      let coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

      for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          let content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, there's a way of using and achieving what you want by setting CSS property `display`, but in that case you have to remove property inside of CSS called `overflow` (basically delete it) -> it's placed inside of `.content`, here's full code of it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .collapsible {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      .content {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        display:none;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      }
      .active,
      .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">current</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        let coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

        for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            let content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
               content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
               content.style.display = "block";
            }
          });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did also try this suggestion from the W3 website, but the behaviour is the same

Comment: @cillianreilly please check my answer again, I've updated it for you

Comment: Thanks, your first method works as a standalone piece of code. But when I put into my larger html file, it doesn't work. Is there anything I should look out for in my larger file?

Comment: I've ended up building my page around this, rather than including this into the page. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

1- put your script out of the body.

2- After I did that, there is still another problem. An extra click at the beginning. why are you using all this script? if it's only one element, then you don't need a loop. let me know if it's only one and I'll update the answer with a less and better script.

Anyway, I fixed it in your script by checking if display != none.

3- If you want some smooth animation, then you should use height instead of display then set the transition to 1s.

```html
<body>
       <style>
        .collapsible {
                background-color: #eee;
                color: #444;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 18px;
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
                text-align: left;
                outline: none;
                font-size: 15px;
                border: 1px solid;
                }

        .content {
                padding: 0 18px;
                display: block;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: white;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                border: 1px solid red;
                }

        .active, .collapsible:hover {
                background-color: #ccc;
                }
        </style>
       
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">current</button>
        <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>

</body>

<script>
    
      const coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
       coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            let content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display != "none") {
                     content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                     content.style.display = "block";
            }
      });
    }
    
</script>
```

---

Edit: regarding your comment:

for that then just use this one from w3schools, it works fine for me.

```html
<style>
        .collapsible {
          background-color: #777;
          color: white;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 18px;
          width: 100%;
          border: none;
          text-align: left;
          outline: none;
          font-size: 15px;
        }
        
        .active, .collapsible:hover {
          background-color: #555;
        }
        
        .content {
          padding: 0 18px;
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>
        
        <p>A Collapsible:</p>
        <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        
        <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
        <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        
        <script>
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;
        
        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.maxHeight){
              content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            } 
          });
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, ultimately I do want multiple collapsible segments

Comment: Thanks, these also work as standalone pieces of code. But in my larger html file, they don't work. Currently the only other thing on the webpage is a navbar.

Comment: @cillianreilly I don't understand the issue, is it possible to share a live example for your large HTML or website? do you want to do this feature on other elements on your page instead of creating new elements? is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can designate exactly which element(s) is/are controlled by each specific button , regardless of where they are located within the DOM. You simply need to add a data attribute to the button with the the selector for the element(s) it should control. On click, pass the attribute value to `document.querySelectorAll()` to find the element(s). Also, it is easiest to have CSS classes for the different visibility states and your script only has to add/remove classes to show/hide the element(s).

```js
const coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //console.log(this.dataset.toggle)
    let content = document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.toggle);
    if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.classList.remove('active')
      content.forEach(el => el.classList.add('collapsed'))
    } else {
      this.classList.add('active')
      content.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('collapsed'))
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible" data-toggle="#past">past</button>
<button type="button" class="collapsible" data-toggle="#current">current</button>
<button type="button" class="collapsible" data-toggle=".nested_elsewhere">nested elsewhere</button>
<div id="current" class="content collapsed">
  <p>Current...</p>
</div>
<div id="past" class="content collapsed">
  <p>Past...</p>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      yup<br>
      <span class="nested_elsewhere collapsed">hello</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      yup<br>
      <span class="nested_elsewhere collapsed">hello</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      yup<br>
      <span class="nested_elsewhere collapsed">hello</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```